# Chrome analyse all audio from web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

Does anyone know how to create a MediaElementSource or any other object that can be used to send ALL sound data that is being played on a webpage through an Analyser from createAnalyser()? I want to be able to use the Analyser without knowing where exactly the sound is coming from.

EDIT: I have accomplished what I wanted but not by capturing all audio. The following block gets you an analyser on a Google Play Music player page (only tested from my library, not the store).

```
ctx = new (window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
source = iVisual.ctx.createMediaElementSource($('audio')[0]);
analyser = iVisual.ctx.createAnalyser();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the audio elements are not supposed to be playing at the same time, but if you still want to do it with all audio elements, I will provide you some code sample to do it. Here's the for loop that runs for every audio file you have, which it will create an audio element for with the appropriate source, and then create a sourcenode for that (createMediaElementSource), and connect that sourcenode to the analyser.

```
onload = function () { //this will be executed when the page is ready
    window.audioFiles = ['audio1.mp3', 'audio2.mp3',...]; //the array with all audio files
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    //now we take all the files and create a button for every file

    sources = []; //we create an array where we store all the created sources in.
    for (var x in audioFiles) {
        var elem = document.createElement('audio'); //create an audio element
        elem.src = audioFiles[x]; //append the specific source to it.

        sources[x] = context.createMediaElementSource(elem); //create a mediasource for it
        sources[x].connect(analyser); //connect that to the analyser
    }

}
```